# Quick Disconnects / Connectors for 24VAC Power - Project Box

Tags: connector, wiring

I have a small project in which I will be using 24VAC power that runs through float switches to operate relays (listed below).  The 24VAC will also be used to control a small motorized ball valve (listed below).  I'd like to have panel mounted power connectors on the project box (which will house the relays and the transformer) so that I am able to easily plug and unplug the float switches and ball valve.

**A DC connector like this seems like it would work well functionally, but not sure if this should be used with low voltage AC??  Are there any connectors out there that are made to be used with 24VAC and are easily connected/unconnected?**

[image: DC Plug]

Relays to be used:
https://www.grainger.com/product/HONEYWELL-HOME-Magnetic-Relay-2E682

Motorized ball valve to be used:
Electrical Rating: 24 VAC, 60 HZ, 0.48 Amps
https://www.pexuniverse.com/taco-z075t2-sentry-zone-valve

Wiring Diagram:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: I've seen connectors like this used for 24 VAC before. Just check the ratings. In general, DC ratings are going to be lower than AC ratings, because AC extinguishes arcs every half cycle while DC can sustain arcs indefinitely.

Comment: Due to larger inductance if loaded when disconnect there is an arc similar to connecting a large cap. So you can disable that with switches for no arc and long life before disconnect.